# Mac showing two different value of environment variable in two terminal

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ idea in my mac. When I run `echo $GOROOT` from the normal terminal it prints an empty string but when I run `echo $GOROOT` in the terminal of IntelliJ it prints `/usr/local/go` My terminal setting for Intellij is something like bellow. Can someone explain the reason? Also I can't see any entry for `$GOROOT` in the `.zshrc` file

[image]

Comment: Run this command : `find $HOME/ -type f -exec grep GOROOT {} /dev/null \;`

Comment: Maybe it's in the `Edit Configurations` menu, shortcut `SHIFT-PROPELLER-COMMA`